# React router dynamic url parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
h(Route, {
    path:
      '/A/:aId/:B?/:bId?/:C?/:cId?/:D?/:dId?',
    render: ({ history, match }) => App({ history, match }),
  })
```

I am trying to create a route that can have 4 parameters depending on user's actions. `A` & `aId` are part of the base route, as in, they are compulsory. Rest of the url is built later on by the app using `history.push()`. I use `match` to fetch each of those parameters when needed.

The problem I am facing right now, when there isn't any `bId`,`cId` & `dId` on page load and a useraction happens that is supposed to update the url, the url has a bunch of 0s in it.

For instance, if the useraction updates `dId` with a value, the url would become: `/A/15656/B/0/C/0/D/734`.

I am not sure how to create the url in a way that it doesn't have the zeros in it while storing the incoming ids for B,C & D.

The `match.params` is as follows in app:

```
{
  "aId": "15656",
  "b": "b",
  "bId": "145763",
  "c": "c",
  "cId": "17023",
  "d": "d",
  "dId": "5b69ac98ab89a"
}
```

URL is set using the following  function:

```
const setHistory = ({ ...props }) => {
const {
    match: { params },
  } = props;

  const urlParams = {
    aId: props.aId,
    cId: props.c.id || params.cId || 0,
    bId: props.bId || params.bId || 0,
    dId: props.dId || params.dId || 0,
  };

  let url = `/A/${urlParams.aId}/B/${urlParams.bId}/c/${
urlParams.cId
  }/d/${urlParams.dId}`;

  props.history.push(url);
};
```

Comment: How are you creating the url that you use with `history.push`?

Comment: Updated the post.